# Why don't I have the Quorum badge on all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, badges

I have the Quorum badge on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) for having a +2 post on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) but not on, for example, travel.stackexchange.com. Why not?

Comment: You need +2 on meta.travel.SE to get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the sites, other than Stack Overflow, have their own individual Metas.  You need to get a +2 post on each individually attached Meta to get the Quorum badge on each site.